# How to read lines as SIMPLE-BASE-STRING?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

So, the following code

```lisp
(defun read-8bit-lines (path)
  (with-open-file (stream path :element-type 'base-char :external-format :ascii)
    (loop
      for line = (read-line stream nil)
      while line
      collect line)))
```

reads in a file as a list of strings of type `SIMPLE-ARRAY-CHARACTER`. I want to have `SIMPLE-BASE-STRING` instead. I can do that with `coerce`:

```lisp
(defun read-8bit-lines (path)
  (with-open-file (stream path :element-type 'base-char :external-format :ascii)
    (loop
      for line = (read-line stream nil)
      while line
      collect (coerce line 'simple-base-string))))
```

Is there a way to do it without resorting to `coerce`? I'm running sbcl 2.0.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portably, no.  Implementations are free to return whatever kind of string they deem sensible.

I'd use a simple wrapper function and maybe declaim it inline:

```
(declaim (inline read-simple-line))
(defun read-simple-line (stream)
  (some-> (read-line stream nil)
          (coerce 'simple-base-string)))
```

(`Some->` is from `arrows`).

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Would you know if there is a non-portable way specifically for SBCL? (Doesn't seem so at first glass, I've browsed some more through the documentation and could not find anything.)

Comment: @Andrei: I neither.  I couldn't even guess how it would have to look when used.  Some special parameter to `open` or `read-line`?